# Is it possible to call a custom module function in the theme template file?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I created a custom module and there is a simple `hello_world()` function. Is it possible to call this function in the page template file?

Module file looks like this.

```
function choco_custom_newui_total_students(){
return 500;
}

function choco_custom_newui_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['total_students'] = total_students();
}
```

**page--front.tpl.php**

```
<h2><? echo $total_students?></h2>
```

Comment: You should call `choco_custom_newui_total_students()` but not `total_students()`

Comment: That's what i was trying to do since beginning. Why would we write the "preprocess_page" function if it was possible .. any ways , its not working.

Comment: Did you clear cache before running the preprocess function?

Comment: Drush cc all  , and cleared Drupal cache aswell.

Comment: I can think of a list that you can check. [1] ensure `choco_custom_newui` is the module name. [2] see if `choco_custom_newui` module has been enabled. [3] run `print 'stop here'; exit;` and refresh the page to see if the preprocess function is really being implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the checks. It worked. Sorry the module was not enabled :)

Comment: Haha.. good to know.

Comment: I edit my answer with aditional information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but it's not recommended, because in the Model-View-Controller pattern, your logic is in the Controller (in this case your module) and in the View (your `.tpl` file) you should only have code to show the values that comes from the Controller.

The idea is that all variables are prepared in template preprocess functions (in modules or in your `template.php`).

You can implement the `hook_preprocess_page()`:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['my_var'] = hello_world();
}
```

and in your `page.tpl.php` file you can now use `$my_var` to output the value set in your preprocess function:

```
echo $my_var;
```

Comment: thanks, i have updated my question with your code. Still i am unable to output any thing in the TPL file.

Comment: @codestings : bizarre .... despite your prior comment, you still accepted this answer ... Could it be that your module was not enabled? If so please add an extra comment here also, or just delete the prior comment. To Adrian: maybe refine your answer to explan WHY it is not recommended? Eg because you should not do so on Merci-giving-day?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I added a few lines if you want you can edit the answer too.

Comment: Why only a ***single*** line (there's room enough for an entire chapter ...). Moreover, I don't think I'll edit it, since I just used the opportunity to hijack your answer to post a new question I asked myself ... And BTW: ***MVC*** in mainframe-speak is an assembler instruction to perform a "**M**o**V**e **C**haracter" ... (though I realize that's another MVC-thing).