# Call a custom module's function from template file

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

In the same context that this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221201/is-it-possible-to-call-a-custom-module-function-in-the-theme-template-file/258292?noredirect=1#comment315686_258292), I want to add a link to a function in my custom module from a template file.

Something like this:

In my template file: `<a href="mymodule_my_function()" id="20">Action</a>`

In my custom module

`function my_function($id){ 
//update data base 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a function doesn't have a url unless you set up a callback url for it first with [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x). Then you can point your link to it and process the data. So in your case it'd look something roughly like that:

In your custom module:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['some_url/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_myfunction',
    'page arguments' => array(
      1,
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_myfunction($id) {
 // update database
}
```

Then in your template use l() as Kevin mentioned (you should adjust to fit your variables etc):

```
print l('Action', 'abc/20');
```

This is very simplified. You'd want to probably enable some access limitations on that new url (abc/%) etc and you can read more about that in the hook_menu docs I linked to above.

Comment: You should also generate these links with `l()` function too, not raw anchor tags.

Comment: good catch, edited

Comment: You may also want to check out the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module which has an example [menu_example](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/menu_example?h=7.x-1.x) sub-module. It will give you an overall idea how to accomplish the task in hand.

Comment: But how can I read my parameters $id in mymodule_myfunction? **print l(t('Action'), 'my_link', array('attributes' => array('id' => array('26'))));**

Comment: it should be like **print l(t('Action'), 'my_link/'.$id);** Thank you